# Send Validated User to New URL

Tags: url

I am trying to point a Wordpress template tag to direct new users via the authentication link in their verification email to my Activate page. The current link sends them to my home page. Here is the existing code:

```
$url = is_multisite() ? get_blogaddress_by_id( (int) $blog_id) : home_url ('', 'http');
```

I looked up the home_url template tag in the WP Codex and it looks like this:

```
<?php home_url( $path, $scheme ); ?>
```

The $path parameters are: (string) (optional) Path relative to the home URL. Default: None

I believe I want to add the relative page link as the $path but I am getting the syntax wrong or something. I tried

```
home_url ('activate', 'http');
```

along with a few other combinations but no luck. I am new to coding and looking for some help with defining this template tag correctly. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use pure php code

```
header('Location:yourlocation');
```